# How to use compact serialization in hazelcast in kubernetes cluster

Tags: hazelcast

I tried to follow [this](https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.1/serialization/compact-serialization) tutorial with compact serialization but I don't know what is the workflow when I want to use it with custom `CompactSerializer`

So I have object Employee which I want to de/serialize. When I installing hazelcast in kubernetes I need to add jar with this class. Now I want add field which should  be supported in schema evolution:

> Compact serialization permits schemas and classes to evolve by adding
> or removing fields, or by changing the types of fields. More than one
> version of a class may live in the same cluster and different clients
> or members might use different versions of the class.

but how I can add this class to running hazelcast in kubernetes without reinstalling it ?

When I add this serializer in my application

```
hzConfig.getSerializationConfig().getCompactSerializationConfig().setEnabled(true);
    hzConfig.getSerializationConfig().getCompactSerializationConfig().register(Employee.class, "employee",
            new EmployeeSerializer());
```

this will be used just in serialization inside hazelcast cluster. But when I want to deserialize object from hazelcast client and I did not use this serializer I got exception that GenericRecord can not be cast to Employee

So I am curious if there is tutorial of workflow how to use this compact serialization with custom object

Comment: If you want to deserialize the object from the client, you should add the same serializer configuration to it as well. Otherwise, Hazelcast client will return you a GenericRecord (which cannot be cast to your Employee class, as expected). You can either add the serializer to your client as well or operate on this generic record instance instead of your class in the client.

Comment: but how I can change class in runtime without reinstaling client ?

Comment: Do you want to dynamically change the serializer you are using in the client? There is no way of doing it (and probably won't be). The idea behind class evolution is that, if you evolve your class in the later versions of your application, you will be able to read data written by old clients. Or, if the both new and old versions of your application is running, they will be able to interoperate for the same data, despite them having different versions of classes and serializers (let's say with extra fields)

Comment: then maybe I just dont understand compact serialization at all. I see no benefits using it in kubernetes cluster instead of Serializable when my model change I need to rebuilt it again

Comment: The good thing is that you don't have to restart your cluster, your clients can be upgraded separately. Some of your clients might work with the initial version of the class(without any restarts), and some might work with the new version of the class, and they can still interoperate on the same data, one might read data written by another.

I really don't get what you have imagined. How will you use the new version of your class in your application without restarting it?